# How to properly save the pointer of a local variable in NSValue for further usage

Tags: objective-c

I've an objective-C function like below:

```
 - (NSValue *)foo:(NSString *)str {
        NSValue* val = [NSValue valueWithPointer: str.UTF8String];

        char* ptr = [val pointerValue];

        return val;
 }
```

It takes in a parameter NSString str. Inside the function, I get UTF8 representation of the the string which is a **copy** of characters of the string (i.e. the pointer for `str` and `str.UT8String` are different).

Now, I store this pointer information in `NSValue` and return this `NSValue` for further usage.
However, I've observed that `str.UTF8String` acts as a local variable to this function is a released as we come out of the function, thus leaving its pointer dangling.

Thus, when I try to use the pointer in `NSValue` to recreate the string, it either returns a `nil` or  random value to me. Occasionally, it also returns true value to me.

How can I safetly save the pointer of `str.UTF8String` for further usage?

Comment: Are you sure that the `NSString` you took the pointer from is not deallocated before you try to access it? Also judging by the docs (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1411189-utf8string?language=objc), the SDK doesn't guarantee this, so you shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: "the string which is a copy of characters" The docs (which Losiowaty linked) specifically say that it's an **internal pointer** whose lifetime is not longer than its owning string. It is not a copy; you must copy it explicitly if you need to extend its lifetime.

Comment: I got it - I incorrectly read the definition of initWithUtf8String. But, even in UTF8String, why does it say, "which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object" - why should it have a lifetime shorter than owning string?